# Como compilar códigos usando o Sublime?

Tags: c++, sublime-text

Gostaria de saber se posso adicionar um compilador ao sublime para compilar coisas direto do programa, mais prático assim.

Answer (score 1):

Como você compila seus programas? Você possui alguma variável de ambiente referenciando um binário para rodar na *linha de comando*? Pois no sublime funciona mais ou menos assim, não sei ao certo nas versões anteriores mas na versão atual o *Sublime Text 3* possui uma área chamada **builds**, do qual você consegue rodar comandos de *building* da sua aplicação.

Não sou desenvolvedor C++ mas utilizo as builds do Sublime diariamente trabalhando com Node.js, portanto creio que seja o mesmo processo. Por agora, irei explicar como funciona o building utilizando Node.js simplesmente por não ter um ambiente C++ instalado. Quando puder me responder aquelas perguntas do ínicio, poderei então atualizar esta resposta com as devidas informações.

### Passo a passo

- Vá em Sublime > Tools > Build System > New Build System

Feito isso creio que o Sublime abriu um novo arquivo com a extensão `.sublime-build` que deverá ser salva dentro de `./Packages/User/`. Segue as configurações do arquivo:

```
{
  "shell_cmd": "node $file"
}
```

> Perceba que onde está `node` deverá ser a variável de ambiente da sua máquina referenciando o binário responsável por compilar seus *scripts* C++ e o parâmetro `$file` é uma referência para o programa atual que será compilado.

- Depois de você ter salvo o arquivo em `./Packages/User/`. Vá em Sublime > Tools > Build System > nome_do_arquivo_que_salvou_anteriormente

Quando você quiser compilar seus programas, pressione `Ctrl + B`.

> **IMPORTANTE**: O Sublime não "mata" o processo, mesmo você pressionando `Ctrl + C` ou `Esc` a building continuará rodando em *background*. Caso você queira por um fim no processo, vá em Sublime > Tools > Cancel Build (a.k.a `Ctrl + Break`).

---

### One more thing...

Atualmente estou utilizando **Windows** então as terminologias que utilizei foram baseados no meu OS. Se estiver utilizando outro sistema creio que terá de fazer uma busca pela "interwebs" a respeito de como configura-las.

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil pra você, ficaria feliz se pudesse marcar ela como a correta.